# How can I append mutliple results from context to one list/variable LINQ C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm working on small app for fetching products/articles, and I wrote a method that's getting articles by type. (types are contained in request arg).

What I'm trying to achieve is: append all results (from all if conditions if they are satisfied) to one main list which should be returned to customer..

When I'm debugging and checking query it says its returning type is `IQueryable<Article>` so basically my question is how can I append multiple `IQueryables` into one which should be returned to user..

This code below is not working because result is always empty..

I've tried also with  `var result = new List<Article>();`  and later  `result.AddRange(query);` and I've changed also return type to
 return await `result.AsQueryable().ToListAsync();` but obviously something breaks somewhere and I get an empty array at the end.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Article>> GetArticlesByType(ArticleObject request)
{
    var result = new Article[] { }.AsQueryable();
    IQueryable<ArticleDTO> query = null;

    if (request.Food.HasValue && (bool)request.Food)
    {
        // Return type of query is IQueryable<Article> 
        query = _context.Articles.Where(x => x.Active == true && x.ArticleType == ArticleType.Food).Select(x => new Article
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            ArticleName = x.ArticleName
        });
        // Here I just wanted if this condition is satisfied to add values to my result
        result.AsQueryable().Union(query);
    }

    if (request.Drink.HasValue && (bool)request.Drink)
    {
        query = _context.Articles.Where(x => x.Active == true && x.ArticleType == ArticleType.Drink).Select(x => new Article
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            ArticleName = x.ArticleName
        });
        // Again if there are any values in query add them to existing result values
        result.AsQueryable().Union(query);
    }

    if (request.Candy.HasValue && (bool)request.Candy)
    {
        // When its candy I want also articles from food category
        query = _context.Articles.Where(x => x.Active == true && x.ArticleType == ArticleType.Food || x.ArticleType == ArticleType.Candy).Select(x => new Article
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            ArticleName = x.ArticleName
        });
        // Again if there are values in query add them to existing result 
        result.AsQueryable().Union(query);
    }
    //At the end return result and all the values in case all conditions were satisfied
    return await result.ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `result.AsQueryable().Union(query.ToList());`. This will fetch the object from database. So far `query` contains references to objects in database and not in your memory

Comment: To expand, `Union()` will merge the distinct values in your `IQueryable`s into one. If you however just wanted them to be merged regardless of duplicate values, you can use `Concat()` instead.